# Create shortcut for PHP

Tags: symlink, php

I have `XAMPP` installed and my PHP is:

`/opt/lampp/bin/php-5.3.8`

Every time I need to execute a PHP file I need to do this:

`/opt/lampp/bin/php-5.3.8 testando.php`

Is there another way to execute it besides using symbolic link?

I did this on `/etc/init.d/`:

`sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php-5.3.8 php`

Why when I need to run PHP  I have to do this `./php` instead of just `php`?

And is there a way to do this without the `./`? Like it was installed via `apt-get`?

Comment: /etc/init.d is a place for system service related scripts. You shouldn't be making links there unless you are linking a service. Executables tend to be in /usr/bin, /usr/local/bin, etc.

Comment: Add the directory to your `PATH`. And the symlink belongs to `/usr/local/bin`, not `/etc/init.d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the link in one of the folders listed in your `PATH` variable. Run `echo $PATH` to see the list of paths. Once the link is created in one of those paths, you will no longer need to prepend `./`

Comment: where do I `echo $PATH`?

Comment: From a terminal or console... AKA the "command line"

Answer (score 2):

`php` wasn't a boot script , you should never put that in `/etc/init.d`

Normally you should have a symbol link named `php` in `/opt/lampp/bin/` , which is linked to `/opt/lampp/bin/php-5.3.8`

(If not , do `ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php-5.3.8 /opt/lampp/bin/php` to make this work)

And in your ~/.bashrc , add more path to $PATH:

`export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin/`

And you execute your script like this , on any directory:

`php XX.php`

Answer (score 0):

Make a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from the executable you want to execute by name to a location in your [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).

```
ln -s ../../../opt/lampp/bin/php-5.3.8 /usr/local/bin/php
```

The default PATH does not contain the current directory, because it's uncommon to change to a directory containing an executable before executing it.

Don't mess up with system directories. `/etc/init.d` contains scripts that start and stop system services; this is not the place to put a link to an interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Make a file /etc/profile.d/php_alias.sh::

> alias php='/opt/lampp/bin/php-5.3.8'

(restart bash)